# Howto enable the expand button in a devexpress Treelist

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a winforms form with a DevExpress TreeList on it.
The Treelist is drawn as expected.
But the indicator known as "expand button" is missing.

According to the DevExpress Manual the button could be disabled with

```
OptionsView.ShowButtons = false;
```

However the TreeList.OptionView.ShowButton value is true.

(It is true during debugging, also no change if I explicitly set it to false and then again to true during initialization)

Which settings can be done so that the "expand button" disappears other then ShowButtons = false?

Comment: This will only show if you have multiple levels of nodes, do you?

Comment: @ScottWylie yes. I used the MyData from https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5561 as a blueprint for the objects. I have multiple levels, i also can see other levels it if i double-click on a StateImage. Normaly you would have something like [expand][stateimage]|fields . In this case i have only [stateimage]|fields. I also tried and removed the statimages - then it looks like [{empty}]|fields (where {empty} is just an empty space )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the root visible :

```
treeList1.OptionsView.ShowRoot = true;
```